# ¿Cómo obtener IMEI en Xamarin.Android?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, permisos, requests

Tengo que hacer una App en Xamarin (Android) donde el cliente me pidió que en vez de loguearse como se hace normalmente (usuario y contraseña) valide si el IMEI del teléfono corresponde al que tiene asignado el usuario.

Por lo que encontré en internet, la forma de hacerlo es la siguiente:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)GetSystemService(TelephonyService);
string imei = tm.GetImei(0);
```

Pero cuando completo la variable imei me sale un error que dice que no tengo los permisos necesarios, por más que ya los marqué en el `Manifest`.
Por lo que tengo entendido, Esto surge porque hay que pedir permiso al usuario cuando el dispositivo tiene Android 6.0 o superior (Yo lo estoy probando en un Moto G5S con Android 8.1).

Busqué la solución a este problema y lo unico que encontré fueron algunos ejemplos de como se hace con Android Studio. En la mayoría de los casos termina siendo de la siguiente forma:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT  < Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
    //Menores a Android 6.0
    String imei= getIMEI();
    return imei;
} else {
    // Mayores a Android 6.0
    String imei="";
    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
        imei="";
    } else {
        imei= getIMEI();
    }

    return imei;

}
```

Alguien podría ayudarme a convertir lo de Android en Xamarin? Porque hace poco que estoy desarrollando en Xamarin y no tengo mucha idea de como pasarlo.

Aclaro por las dudas que mi proyecto **no es de Xamarin.Forms**, es un proyecto Xamarin Android que estoy desarrollando con Visual Studio.

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De esta manera se escribe el código que publiqué en la pregunta:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
{
    //Menores a Android 6.0
    imei = tm.GetImei(0);
}
else
{
    //Mayores a Android 6.0
    int permissionCheck = Convert.ToInt32(ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Android.Manifest.Permission.ReadPhoneState));

    if (permissionCheck != PermissionChecker.PermissionGranted){ ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new string[] { Android.Manifest.Permission.ReadPhoneState }, 0);
    imei = "";
    }else{
        imei = tm.GetImei(0);
    }
}
```

La primera vez que entremos a la App va a pedir los permisos, la segunda va a devolver el IMEI sin problemas mediante la siguiente sentencia:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)GetSystemService(TelephonyService);
string imei = tm.GetImei(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con este código:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(UniqueIdAndroid))]
namespace UniqueId.Droid
{
    public class UniqueIdAndroid : IDevice
    {
        public string GetIdentifier()
        {
            return Settings.Secure.GetString(Forms.Context.ContentResolver, Settings.Secure.AndroidId);
        }
    }
}
```

Y luego

```
string deviceIdentifier = DependencyService.Get<IDevice>().GetIdentifier();
```

Comment: Esto no sería para Xamarin.forms? Porque no me funciona